# Can't send data from my cellphone to firebase

Tags: database, firebase, unity-game-engine

When i test my application in unity i can send data to my firebase database(username,age,pass), but exporting the apk to my cellphone, firebase does not recibe the data.
I'm connected to wifi so i don't know what's happening, if someone could help me i will be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with usb debugging?

Comment: Yes, and still not working:(

Comment: i mean, i tested it with usb debugging and still not working

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to send data at all in unity unless they fixed that in the last few months. You can send information on an actual device however.

The problem might be that you didn't add the correct Configure file. Check link below.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592

Also only have one config file per project. If you build to iOS first then android delete iOS config file then add the correct one.

Firebase has two different files for different platforms.